# Why is the power output of a power only cable on a USB Y-Cable so poor?

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, power-supply, android

From the power only cable I get 310mA at best
If I use the Data+Power end I get 1000+mA

I have an android head unit in my car and the power output it pathetic, I get roughly 200mA from that and as I use Android Auto with the phone connected to the head unit via USB cable and it it slowly drains the battery.

My Android Head unit has a USB cable connected, then an android auto dongle then a cable from the dongle to my phone.

I was going to plug in a cable from the dongle to the female end of the USB Y Cable, then with the two male connections (one data+power and the other power) the data+power plugging into my phone, and then the power plugged into a 12v cigarette charger which usually charges my phone quickly. But I seem to get 200-300mA max!

I'm just wondering why this is and how can I increase the power output of the Android Radio? My radio is a cheap (£169) Chinese radio stating it's Android 10 but it's actually android 8.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally devices are only allowed [up to 500 mA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_hardware#Allowable_current_draw) (at 5 V) from a standard USB 2.0 type-A port. Phones and chargers implement a negotiation protocol, such as QuickCharge or USB Battery Charging, which allows the phone to ask for more power (a higher current limit and/or higher voltage).

But this negotiation is primarily done through the USB *data* lines, so with an Y-cable that only connects power, your phone is only able to talk to the head unit, not to the charger.

(With the Y-cable the phone *could* probably draw a little bit more, but I'd generally assume that it deliberately limits its current draw if it's unable to do the QC handshake with the charger, even if the charger itself does not. These Y-cables were meant to be used with devices that were *designed* to expect such a connection.)